# Why the size of Zookeeper log block is not 64M?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I started zookeeper cluster in my computer, it's includes three instances.By default the size of log file should be 64M, but i found a strange things
[image]

If anyone can explain what happened with Zookeeper?

here is the content of the log file 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `FileTxnLog` is truncated, which is implemented by `FileTxnSnapLog.truncateLog`.

This scenario happens when there is a new election, and follower has some transaction that is not committed in leader.

This can be verified if log like:

```
Truncating log to get in sync with ...
```

exists in `zookeeper.out` or the log file you specified.

Comment: i had checked the content of the log file in detail, but not found you said above.

Comment: Where can I see what you said?

Comment: @青松周 can you attach the info of the log at '7-24 12:40' to your original question ?

Comment: hi, i upload the picture of log file contents.

Comment: @青松周 not that log.. that's the data log.. can you find the application log of zookeeper, it's normally 'zookeeper.out' or the file you specified in conf/log4j.properties

Comment: Unfortunately, also i found that file. But the contents of the log file are not expected, I already checked all files. Thanks a lot.